# How exactly can I find the pallindrome of a 32 bit number using ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, palindrome

I was trying to find an assembly code to find whether the given number is a palindrome. I got a code online. But I am not able to understand the 'movu' command. Can anyone explain?

```
mov R0,1044480
mov R3,0
mov R4,31
movu R2,0x0001
mov R5,0
andu R1,R0,0xffff

.loop:
and R3,R2,R1
lsl R2,R2,1
lsl R3,R3,R4
add R5,R5,R3
sub R4,R4,2
cmp R4,0
bgt .loop
lsr R0,R0,16
lsr R5,R5,16
sub R0,R5,R0
cmp R0,0
beq .palin
mov R0,0

b .exit

.palin:
mov R0,1

.exit:
```

Comment: what part do you not understand?

Comment: If you want to know whether it's a palindrome in base 2, the `RBIT` instruction would help :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of questions here.  Why are you doing this in assembly when you don't seem overly familiar with the instruction set?  What device are you writing this assembly code for?  Surely if you're doing assembly, you should at least have the instruction set documentation for the processor?

Now let's deal with the question itself.  movu is the mnemonic for MOV Unsigned.  This essentially works the same way as the MOV instruction, the difference being that it does not alter the status register, unlike MOV.  This way you can move a register to a destination without changing, for example the Z, C or N flags.

Comment: I was just trying to prepare for my interviews and also I wanted to check how exactly the stackoverflow works. I had learnt few basic instruction long time ago, and I didn't know much of it. But thanks for answering my question :)